# Replace values in dataframe given count of group by

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, replace, filter

I have a dataframe of categorical variables. I want to replace all the fields in one column with an arbitrary unique string if the count of that category within the column is less than 100.

So, for example, in column color, if any color appears less than 100 times i want it to be replaced by the string "base"

I tried the below code and tried different things I found on stack overflow.

```py
df['color'] = numpy.where(df.groupby("color").filter(lambda x: len(x) < 100), 'dummy', df['color'])
```

Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (45638872,878) () (8765878782788,)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need this,

```
df.loc[df.groupby('color')['color'].transform('count')<100, 'color']= 'dummy'
```